LADR $7D$ $Q18$ Show $T$ is uniformly continuous with respect to metric on $V$.
This question is from Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd edition.
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Show that $T$ is uniformly continuous with respect
to the metric $d$ on $V$ defined by $d(u, v)=\|u-v\|$.
_ _
This is the first time I believe he has mentioned uniformly continuous in the book, and I am not sure what it means for a linear map to be uniformly continuous with respect to a metric $d$ on $V$. My understanding is that a metric is just the distance between two points.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you. I have read a bit of the wikipedia entry on uniform continuity (https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=uniform+continuiuty&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), but unsure how to actually apply it to this question.

Actually, it's the only reference to uniform continuity in the whole book.

What is the difference between continuity and uniform continuity?
Function between metric spaces $f:(X, d) \to (Y, \rho)$ is continuous, when it is continuous in each point. This can be written as
$$ \left(\forall x \in X\right) \left(\forall \varepsilon > 0 \right) \left(\exists \delta > 0\right) \left( \forall x' \in X \right)\quad d(x, x') < \delta \implies \rho(f(x), f(x')) < \varepsilon.$$
Order of $\forall$ quantifiers standing next to each other can be always exchanged, so this could be written as
$$  \left(\forall \varepsilon > 0 \right)\left(\forall x \in X\right) \left(\exists \delta > 0\right) \left( \forall x' \in X \right)\quad d(x, x') < \delta \implies \rho(f(x), f(x')) < \varepsilon.$$
Uniform continuity is very similar. It reads
$$  \left(\forall \varepsilon > 0 \right) \left(\exists \delta > 0\right) \left(\forall x \in X\right)\left( \forall x' \in X \right)\quad d(x, x') < \delta \implies \rho(f(x), f(x')) < \varepsilon,$$
which is often shortened to
$$  \left(\forall \varepsilon > 0 \right) \left(\exists \delta > 0\right) \left( \forall x, x' \in X \right)\quad d(x, x') < \delta \implies \rho(f(x), f(x')) < \varepsilon.$$
From purely logic point of view, this is clearly stronger condition, that is uniform continuity implies continuity. This is because in general $(\exists \alpha )(\forall \beta )\varphi(\alpha, \beta)$ implies $(\forall \beta )(\exists \alpha) \varphi(\alpha, \beta)$ but not the other way around.
From more topological point of view, the $\delta$ which appears in definition of continuity can be chosen uniformly for all $x \in X$ in case of uniform continuity.
Linear functions
Given continuous linear operator $T:V \to V$, where $V$ is normed space, we mean that continuity is with respect to the metric induced by the norm, that is $d(x, y) = \|x - y \|$. Here $X = Y = V$, and $d = \rho$.
Assuming continuity, we may prove uniform continuity as follows:
continuous operators are bounded, that is there exists number $\|T\|$ such that for any $x, x'$ we have $\|Tx - Tx'\| \leq \|T\| \|x - x'\|$. Now
$$ d(Tx, Tx') = \|Tx - Tx'\| \leq \|T\| \|x - x'\| = \|T\| d(x, x'), $$
so for given $\varepsilon > 0$ we may choose $\delta$ to be $\frac \varepsilon {\|T\|}$ when $T \neq 0$ and any number when $T = 0$.
